# Google ads script error when trying to run a script with GPT API for RSAs

Tags: scripting

Im trying to run this script using a GPT API key, but I keep getting an error.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') at generateTextOpenAI (Code:222:13) at main (Code:102:23) at Object. (adsapp_compiled:19646:54)

https://gist.github.com/siliconvallaeys/2dc8eb8b8f2fc992428ab2b66ce78f2f#file-gpt-suggestions-for-rsas-with-google-ads-scripts

Tried changing api key.